# Recursion - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, recursion, logic

I need to sort out the values in such a way that the toReturn list should contain the following:

```
Test(1100, 1130)
Test(1134, 1200)
Test(1210, 1310)
Test(1100, 1140)
Test(1145, 1210)
Test(1220, 1320)
```

I get:

```
Test(1100, 1130)
Test(1134, 1200)
Test(1210, 1310)
Test(1100, 1140)
Test(1145, 1210)
Test(1134, 1200)
Test(1220, 1320)
```

Basically, looping through the three lists and checking if the Start of second is > End of first.

I have tried various ways to solve this and this the closest I could get, but still don't get the results as I expect.

Can someone please advise what I might be doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication22
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<Test> toReturn = new List<Test>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Test> l1 = new List<Test>();
            l1.Add(new Test(1100, 1130));
            l1.Add(new Test(1100, 1140));
            l1.Add(new Test(1110, 1150));

            List<Test> l2 = new List<Test>();
            l2.Add(new Test(1134, 1200));
            l2.Add(new Test(1145, 1210));

            List<Test> l3 = new List<Test>();
            l3.Add(new Test(1210, 1310));
            l3.Add(new Test(1220, 1320));

            List<List<Test>> container = new List<List<Test>>();
            container.Add(l1);
            container.Add(l2);
            container.Add(l3);

            sort(container, 0, 0);
        }

        private static void sort(List<List<Test>> temp, int position, int time)
        {
            if (position + 1 == temp.Count)
            {
                return;
            }

            List<Test> tt = temp[position];

            if (position + 1 < temp.Count)
            {
                List<Test> tt1 = temp[position + 1];

                for (int i = 0; i < tt.Count; i++)
                {
                    int t1 = tt[i].End;

                    for (int j = 0; j < tt1.Count; j++)
                    {
                        int t2 = tt1[j].Start;

                        if (t2 > t1 && t2 > time)
                        {
                            //if (toReturn.Count == 0)
                            //{
                            if (toReturn.Count == 0)
                            {
                                toReturn.Add(tt[i]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (toReturn[toReturn.Count - 1].End != tt[i].End && toReturn[toReturn.Count - 1].Start != tt[i].Start)
                                {
                                    toReturn.Add(tt[i]);
                                }
                            }

                            if (toReturn[toReturn.Count - 1].End != tt1[j].End && toReturn[toReturn.Count - 1].Start != tt1[j].Start)
                            {
                                toReturn.Add(tt1[j]);
                            }

                            sort(temp, position + 1, tt1[j].End);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (position > 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            String val = "";
            //return toReturn;
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        int start;

        public Test(int val1, int val2)
        {
            Start = val1;
            End = val2;
        }

        public int Start
        {
            get { return start; }
            set { start = value; }
        }

        int end;

        public int End
        {
            get { return end; }
            set { end = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OrderBy with custom comparator should be much smaller and safer...

Comment: What results do you get instead?

Comment: Edited the post to show what I get.

Answer (score 1):

Use a comparator, as suggested: An element is less than another if its End is less than the other's Start. An element is greater than another if its Start is greater than the other's End.

```
class TestComparer : IComparer<Test>
{
    int Compare(Test a, Test b)
    {
        if (a.End < b.Start) return -1;
        else if (a.Start > b.End) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
...
List.Sort(list, new TestComparer());
```

**Edit** After re-reading your question, I would follow an approach like the one below:

- While there is an element left in the list
- Find element with smallest Start

  - Add it to the resulting list, and remove it from the list
  - While an element with a larger Start then the last item's End in the resulting list exists

    - Add it to the resulting list, and remove it from the list

Something like:

```
while (list.Count > 0)
{
    int i = GetSmallestTestIdx(list);
    do
    {
        result.Add(list[i]);
        list.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    while ((i = GetNextTextIdx(list, result)) != -1);
}
```

Comment: I can use the comparator, that is not a problem. How will I loop through the three (or more) lists and get the results is the issue.

Comment: What do you mean? You want a sorted list, correct? This will produce it... Simply combine the lists, and use the last line to sort it.

Comment: +1. [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345618.aspx) can flatten lists if needed.

Comment: I do wanted sorted, but there is a slight catch to it. If you have a look at the results that I want, have a look at item no. 4 onwards. The sorting begins again after one set of results is added.

Comment: I edited my answer, clarify further for more help, I'm still not sure I fully understand the question.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Maybe I wasn't too clear in the question that I asked. This is to do with bus timetable. The 3 lists denote the times a service departs from a particular spot.

List l1 is times from stop A to B, l2 is stop B to C and l3 is from stop C to D. If someone has to travel from A to D, they will need to be shown connecting services, and the connecting service has to depart after the arrival of the previous service. That's the reason the sorting has to be in that particular order.